# iOS 7 rotation issue, working fine in iOS5/iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, screen-rotation

I have a navigation controller application which has worked perfectly in iOS5/iOS6 overloading the rotation methods in a category as explained in this GIST:  https://gist.github.com/lessthanyouthink/3842178 the only difference is that the GIST subclass  UINavigationController and I put it in a category. The problem comes when I'm accessing a viewcontroller which supports all orientations put the orientation in landscape and going back to a portrait only viewcontroller. In iOS 6 the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation method is called but not in iOS 7, so it doesnt autorotate to portrait unless I do it (turning the phone).

Any clues about this ??

Comment: Overriding methods in a category is never a good idea. See if the problem persists if you create a subclass like in the Gist you posted.

Comment: It worked fine... I wonder why exactly did this fail or more exactly why it worked fine before. Thanks !!